# Converting dataframe columns to arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert my dataframe columns to arrays. For example, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Total  Price   Carrier
2      3       C
1      5       D
```

I'd like to convert the columns to arrays like this: `[[2, 1], [3,5], ['C','D]]` I do not want the column names.

I've tried doing this:

```
df["all"] = 1
df.groupby("all")[["Total","Price", "Carrier"]].apply(list)
```

However, I get something like this `["Total", "Price", "Carrier"]` and is an object and not an array. How can I convert all columns to arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `df.values` instead of `apply`:

```
>>> df.values.T.tolist()
[[2, 1], [3, 5], ['C', 'D']]
```